# The serializable class Employee does not declare a static final serialVersionUID field of type long

Tags: java, eclipse, serialization, serialversionuid

In my Eclipse I was trying example on serialization and I came across following warning

[image]

I know what serialVersionUID is and what is it's significance in Serialization. I have following questions about this warning

1. How does IDE assign default value. Is it hard coded in the IDE?
2. When it says generate id what parameters are used to generate new id?
3. Not sure what the 3rd option is.  Says something about suppress annotation. Does that mean no id is assigned at all. In that case what is used in serialization?

Comment: Read this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285793/what-is-a-serialversionuid-and-why-should-i-use-it

Comment: Suggestion: Since first two questions are strictly about `Eclipse`, add it as a tag.

Comment: It seems to me that options `2` and `3` are *basically* the same as far as `serialVersionUID` itself is concerned: you will not get warnings at compile-time and Java will generate an ID for you at run-time.

Comment: Apparently not. Option 2 will generate serialVersionUID which will remain constant and will be used there after. Even if the class is modified later this value being the same will not affect serializarion/deserialization process. Whereas 3rd option will give a value at runtime which will differ in case class is modified later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How does IDE assign default value. Is it hard coded in the IDE?

yes default is hard coded value, which is `1L`

> When it says generate id what parameters are used to generate new id?

generally method fields and method signatures should used to determine it, since you are asking specifically about eclipse, not sure about it, there is a [`serialver`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/serialver.html) utillity which simply gives you serialVersionUID for your class

```
$serialver A
serialver A:    static final long serialVersionUID = -609421954100196333L;
```

> Not sure what the 3rd option is. Says something about suppress annotation. Does that mean no id is assigned at all. In that case what is used in serialization?

it says, instruct java compiler to not complain about this particular warning for this case by adding `@SuppressWarning` annotation

---

**Also See**

- [Eclipse auto-generation of serialVersionUID with each change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464529/eclipse-auto-generation-of-serialversionuid-with-each-change)
- [About generated serialVersionUID in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10389180/about-generated-serialversionuid-in-eclipse)